# Windows Server on Domain Does Not Have a Record in DNS

Tags: networking, dns, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, administration

Our DNS Server (2008) is working fine but for some reason it has not created an A record for a Windows 2012 machine we joined to the domain.

Running "ipconfig /registerdns" on the 2012 machine yields nothing and nothing obvious in the event log gets recorded either.

We have other 2012 machines that have A records created no problem.

Already tried un-joining and rejoining to the domain. Creating an A record manually is not an option because it causes unexpected behavior such as errors when attempting to remotely manage the machine.

How do we get this machine to register a record on its own?

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess, but you may have an encryption-level mismatch with the signed dynamic update feature in Microsoft DNS.  Check what functional level your domain is running.  If it's running at 2003 level then you don't have the newer encryption types that Windows 2012 uses and if it's not falling back to use RC4 (can be disabled by policy), that would explain the issue on that one machine.

The Event logs on your DNS server should point you in the right direction.